# How to create a custom ImageView with nonrectangular shape?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-imageview

how can I make custom ImageViews in Android like in the picture which all have non-rectangular shapes? I want to be able to load images into these ImageViews and have the images clipped accordingly so that each image stays in its specified area (1,2,3 4). I would preferrably like to specify the shapes of the ImageViews in the layout if that is at all possible.

I also want touches to be recognized only in the exact areas where the ImageViews are.

If not, **is there a way to do it with a canvas** where I define these different areas and then clip the images loaded into them **programatically**?[image]